# Erro 4294963238 - react-native-gesture-handler com EXPO

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

Estou utilizando o Expo juntamente com o React, e quando tento instalar o `react-native-gesture-handler` com o comando expo install `react-native-gesture-handler` tenho o seguinte erro:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/naver/hammer.js.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\tiago\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-15T19_21_47_612Z-debug.log

npm exited with non-zero code: 4294963238
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

### Conteúdo do log:

```
35 verbose stack Error: spawn git ENOENT
35 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
35 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
35 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
36 verbose cwd C:\Users\tiago\Desktop\Project\funcionaMerda3
37 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
38 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
39 verbose node v13.7.0
40 verbose npm  v6.13.6
41 error code ENOENT
42 error syscall spawn git
43 error path git
44 error errno -4058
45 error enoent Error while executing:
45 error enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/naver/hammer.js.git
45 error enoent
45 error enoent
45 error enoent spawn git ENOENT
46 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
47 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

Comment: alguém me ajuda pf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia, basta executar o cmd como administrador e rodar o seguinte comando: `npm install --global windows-build-tools`, feito isso apenas execute expo install react-native-gesture-handler novamente que será um sucesso!

Comment: muito obrigado, funcionou